# Listview and data

Tags: android, listview, textbox, imageview

I have a `ListView` where I have some elements. Every item has one `ListView`and two `TextBoxes`. Here is my question: When I clock on element from the list a new activity starts,  where I have one `ListView` and two `TextBoxes`. How I can do this if I click first element in the new activity in `ListView` will be `ListView`from this item and in `TextBoxes`will be data from `TextBoxes` from the list.

Comment: What is the problem? you can't select the item or get data from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `extras` to the `Intent` you use when starting the new Activity.

Let's say your current activity is `MyActivity`, and the one you want to start by clicking on a list item is `MyNewActivity`; Then in your `MyActivity` class, inside the list item click listener should be modified as:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, MyNewActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("my.picture.id", images[itemPosition]);
intent.putExtra("my.header.id", headers[itemPosition]);
intent.putExtra("my.text.id", texts[itemPosition]);
startActivity(intent);
```

and in your `MyNewActivity` class' `onCreate` method you are able to retrieve the passed extras, and fill the proper fields with the correct values:

```
final Intent intent = getIntent();
final int pictureId = intent.getIntExtra("my.picture.id", 0);
final int headerId = intent.getIntExtra("my.header.id", 0);
final int textId = intent.getIntExtra("my.text.id", 0);

((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.my_image)).setImageResource(pictureId);
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.my_header)).setText(headerId);
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.my_text)).setImageResource(textId);
```

the `images`, `headers` and `texts` arrays -I suppose- contain the resource ids for the images and strings you want to display. They are probably accessible via the data of your current item's renderer.

Comment: This is how I store data:
final item itemsList[] = new item[]{new item(R.drawable.per1,"Zbigniew","Mista"),
    new item(R.drawable.per2,"Zbigniew2","Mista2"),
    new item(R.drawable.per3,"Zbigniew3","Mista3"),
    new item(R.drawable.per4,"Zbigniew4","Mista4")};

how put data from one item to intent?

Comment: that's even easier, then you only have one list (array), you can use the proper getters on your current item's data to retrieve the necessary fields. So instead of using `images[itemPosition]` you can use `currentItem.getImageId()`.

Answer (score 0):

I would go about it a bit differently (in retrieving the information at least) than rekaszeru.

In your first activity you would use onListItemClick and put the information into the extras bundle to be passed with the intent to start the second activity.  In this method, you use the view passed in to retrieve the info, so it doesn't matter what kind of adapter you are using and the position in the adapter doesn't matter.

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(FirstClass.this, SecondClass.class);
    myIntent.putExtra("ImageRef", v.findViewById(R.id.imageview)).getTag());
    myIntent.putExtra("Text1", v.findViewById(R.id.TextView1).getText().toString());
    myIntent.putExtra("Text2", v.findViewById(R.id.TextView2).getText().toString());
    FirstClass.this.startActivity(myIntent);
}
```

Then in the second activity retrieve the info to be used:

```
private TextView NewTextView1;
private TextView NewTextView2;
private ImageViewView NewImageView;

Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

NewTextView1 = (TextView)findViewBYId(R.id.newtextview1).setText(extras.getString("Text1"));
NewTextView2 = (TextView)findViewBYId(R.id.newtextview2).setText(extras.getString("Text2"));
NewImageView = (ImageView)findViewBYId(R.id.newimageview).setImageResource(extras.getInt("ImageRef"));
```